# Google Map; render lat long at certain floor / level of mall

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We render a bunch of maps using a standard lat/lon approach. We have a couple of locations we'd like to render using the Javascript API which are located on the second floor/level of a mall. I.e. - https://www.google.com/maps/place/Oakley+Store/@29.737171,-95.4645031,19z/data=!3m1!5s0x8640c16ee39d1977:0x97b6f0c19a3c4965!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x0000000000000000:0x0e32e92bebcf1ace!2zSCZN!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x069df21743f2db2f

Is there any way to continue to use the lat/lon approach but force google maps into a certain floor of the mall? Our approach right now;

```
var options = {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.737171, -95.4645031),
    map: map
};

// add markers to map
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6wy1v7k2/1/ (Note how 'level 1' appears at the top of the map.)

The location we want to map to doesn't exist in Google Maps like the Oakley store in the above example does so I figure we have to use lat/lon for now.

Comment: Does Google maps have any data for any of the other levels?  If you have that data, you can create [custom maptypes to display them](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay)

Comment: Yes, google contains level 2, level 3 etc. I'm not trying to add an overlay though. I'm trying to get the map to display at level 2 within the store, the detail is already there.

Comment: The API does not support the floorpicker at this stage. It is a potential enhancement. The only solution is to create your own custom overlays.